# my inherited class(boss) won't accept the 3 parameters the main class(employee) accepts

Tags: python-2.7

What is wrong with my code? when i create a new Boss class i can't seem to get all the parameters from employe to work.

```
months = 6

class Employee(object):

    balance = 0
    company_income = 10000000000000000 

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.tasks = {}
        self.fullname = "{} {}".format(self.first, self.last)
        self.email = "{}.{}@Otterstad.com".format(self.first, self.last)

    def finishTask(self, task):
        del self.tasks[task]
    def getMonths(self):
        print self.pay * months


class Manager(Employee):

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay)
        self.employees = []
        self.pay += 10000

    def addTask(self, task):
        if len(self.tasks) == 0:
            self.tasks[1] = task
        else:
            self.tasks[len(self.tasks)+1] = task


class Boss(Employee):

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay)
        self.employees = []

    def changeSalary(self, new_salary):
        self.pay = new_salary

    def giveBonus(self, bonus, employee):
        employee.balance += bonus

    def addTask(self, task):
        if len(self.tasks) == 0:
            self.tasks[1] = task
        else:
            self.tasks[len(self.tasks)+1] = task

st1 = Boss("test", "test", 2000000000)
```

Comment: "i can't seem to get all the parameters from employee to work." To work how?

Comment: oh, that was a little unclear. When I create a Boss called st1, it says that Boss only accepts one parameter instead of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `super` in way that is correct for Python 3, not 2.

In `Boss.__init__`, change

`super().__init__(first, last, pay)`

to

`super(Boss, self).__init__(first, last, pay)`.

Similarly, change the other calls to `super` throughout your code.